# Doob's stopping time proof (discrete)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

I have difficulty in understanding the transition in following statement:

$\mathbb{E}\left( X_{\tau }\right) = \sum _{k=0}^{K}\mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}(X_{k}|\mathscr{F}_{k})1_{\tau=k}] = \sum _{k=0}^{K}\mathbb{E}[X_K1_{\tau=k}] $

**Could you please explain what property is used to replace $\mathbb{E}(X_{k}|\mathscr{F}_{k})$ by $X_K$?**

---

Further details on are from (Bingham, Kiesel 2004). I have highlighted the part, which I cannot grasp :
[image: STP proof from a book Bingham, Kiesel 2004]

Comment: Since $\tau$ is a stopping time, that indicator involving $\tau$ goes inside the conditional expectation and you invoke iterated conditioning.

Comment: I guess you are using the fact that $X_k$ is measurable in $\mathcal{F}_k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\{X_t\}$ is martingale we know that $E[X_K \mid \mathcal{F}_k]=X_k$.

Then, reemplacing $X_k$ we obtain

$E[X_k 1_{(\tau=k)}]=E[E[X_K \mid \mathcal{F}_k] 1_{(\tau=k)}]$. (*)

On the other hand, since $\tau$ is stopping time we have that $1_{(\tau=k)}$ is $\mathcal{F}_k$-measurable. Then , due to an elemental property of conditional expectation, we have
$E[X_K \mid \mathcal{F}_k]1_{(\tau=k)}=E[X_K 1_{(\tau=k)}\mid \mathcal{F}_k]$.

In view of (*), we conclude that 
$E[X_k 1_{(\tau=k)}]=E[E[X_K 1_{(\tau=k)} \mid \mathcal{F}_k] ]$

Finally, due to the definition of conditional expectation $E[X_K 1_{(\tau=k)}]=E[E[X_K 1_{(\tau=k)}\mid\mathcal{F}_k]]$.

We obtain, $E[X_k 1_{(\tau=k)}]=E[X_K 1_{(\tau=k)}]$.

Comment: Thanks for such thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathcal{F}_k$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_1, \dots, X_k$, the Martingale properties gives you that:

$\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n] = X_n$ and $X_n \in \mathcal{F}_n$.